# Javascript inheritance is not working, using the prototype method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I searched on how to inherit an Object and I found that you can use the `Create()` function but it doesn't work.

```
function Animal(strength, team, id /*url*/ ) {
  this.strength = strength;
  this.team = team;
  this.id = id;
  this.can_move = function(position, destination) {
    this.destination = Board[destination[0]][destination[1]]
    if ((position[0] == destination[0] + 1) && (position[1] == destination[1]) ||
      (position[0] == destination[0] - 1) && (position[1] == destination[1]) ||
      (position[1] == destination[1] + 1) && (position[0] == destination[0]) ||
      (position[1] == destination[1] - 1) && (position[0] == destination[0])) {} else {
      console.log('false')
      return false
    }

    if (Board[destination[0]][destination[1]].animal != null) {
      if (this.can_eat(Board[destination[0]][destination[1]].animal)) {
        /*pass*/ } else {
        console.log('false')
        return false
      }
    }
    if (!this.obstacle()) {
      return false;
    }

    console.log('true')
    return true
  }
  this.can_eat = function(animal) {
    if (animal.strength <= this.strength) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
  this.obstacle = function() {
    if (Board[destination[0]][destination[1]].type == "River1" || Board[destination[0]][destination[1]].type == "River2" ||
      Board[destination[0]][destination[1]].type == team + "_goal") {
      console.log("false");
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.move = function(position, destination) {
    //pass
  }
}

function Mouse(team, id) {

}
Mouse.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

Board is an array and if I do a new Mouse it doesn't know what `can_move` is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Board[2][6].animal.can_move is not a function, animal is just an 
attribute of board, it contains Mouse.
```

**Edit:** Thanks,but now it gives me:

```
Cannot set property 'can_move' of undefined
at new Animal.
```

Comment: All the properties you've added are **not** on the `Animal` prototype, that's why `Mouse` does not inherit them through there.

Comment: you also need to call the `Animal` constructor from your `Mouse` constructor

Comment: Unless this is a part of your assignment, I'd recommend to look into classes, which are far easier to work with.

Comment: Small suggestion to paste your JS code here and fix what it says https://jshint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're declaring your functions on the *prototype* of `Animal`

```js
function Animal(){

}
Animal.prototype.can_move = function(){ return true; }

function Mouse(){

}
Mouse.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

const m = new Mouse();
console.log(m.can_move());
```

This is a lot easier using classes

```js
class Animal {
   can_move(){ return true; }
}

class Mouse extends Animal {}

const m = new Mouse();
console.log(m.can_move());
```

Comment: I am gonna use classes instead, thank all of you for your support